# Swiper loop has gap when array is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I use React 18.2.0 and Swiper 11.0.5.

I made an array 0-99 numbers for swiper.

And there is a bug when there is end of array of dom elements swiper shows empty place. When I click on swiper and roll again gap disappears. [gap in right swiper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9aSx.png). Gap also shows up in bottom of swiper.

code:

```
                     <Swiper
                        slidesPerView={5}
                        initialSlide={getInitialSlide(1)}
                        direction={'vertical'}
                        loop={true}
                        modules={[Navigation]}
                        onSlideChange={(slide) => handleSlideChange(slide, 1)}
                        centeredSlides={true}
                        navigation={true}
                        className="swiper--left"
                    >
                        {points.map((item, index) => (
                            <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                                <div>{item}</div>
                            </SwiperSlide>
                        ))}
                    </Swiper>
```

I noticed that gap shows up when "transform: translate3d" of swiper-wrapper class has positive centeral number.

I expect endless loop works without gap.
I tried to change styles as position. But it didn't help

css for left swiper:

```
.swiper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  .swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: var(--palette-live-grey-3);
    height: 50px !important;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .swiper-slide-active {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: var(--palette-live-grey-0);
  }

  .swiper-slide-prev,
  .swiper-slide-next {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: var(--palette-live-grey-7);
  }
}

.swiper--left {
  position: relative !important;

  .swiper-button-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      height: 2px;
      width: 20px;
      background-color: var(--palette-live-grey-7);
    }
  }

  .swiper-button-next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25%;
    left: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    &::before {
      content: "";
      display: inline-block;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background:
        linear-gradient(var(--palette-live-grey-7), var(--palette-live-grey-7)),
        linear-gradient(var(--palette-live-grey-7), var(--palette-live-grey-7));
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 50% 2px, 2px 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }

  .swiper-wrapper {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some codes so we could help

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju . Added code in question